# winforms control for viewing object details

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, debugging

I need to display some sort of detailed information about an object in my custom win form application.

something similar as visual studio uses when debugging. does any of you know something that might help.

I know, I can write something on my own, but I don't intent to.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can try the `PropertyGrid` control. This is the control you use to configure control properties in the Windows Forms designer.

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)

Comment: forgot to mention. Although i can use it, its not exactly what i need. I think more about debug viewer where all complex properties do not need to be decorated with some designer attributes. 

The problem with property grid is when showing collections, or some complex types. thats where debug view is much closer to what i want to achive.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use the PropertyGrid then you have little choice but to write your own control. There is no standard WinForm control for what you intend. I also have never seen such a control provided by the control vendors either.

To build your own you would need to use a TreeView control but with two columns. The left with a hierarchy of the objects and the right column with object values. I would recommend using a control vendors grid control for this.